# Changing position creates loss of quality in Premiere Pro CS5

Tags: premiere, cs5, video-quality

I have a Premiere Pro (CS5) project with raw files that are of good quality (image looks sharp), etc. When I export it, no matter what settings, it looks worse. At first I thought it was an OS X vs. Windows problems, but eventually I pinpointed the problem:

Clips for which I changed the position (slight moves up or down to better center the frame), without any further effect, result in a noticeable loss of quality (even without ANY encoder).

Did anyone encounter such a thing? 
Do you know of a way to solve this?

Comment: Can you link to some samples of before and after for both moved and unmoved video?

Comment: Are you moving whole pixels? Moving half/partial pixels would result in anti-aliasing as the program blends adjacent pixels to make the correct colour.

Comment: This is most likely a resampling problem like @nchpmn suggests. It could also have to do with the codec you're using for your output. If you're using a 4:2:2 or other chroma-subsampling codec, you can also see degradation in the resolution of the outputs. It can be particularly noticeable in the saturated reds and blues.